# Add line breaks to mysql textarea

Tags: php, mysql, line-breaks

I create a simple backed area for my client to post new job openings and was wanting to give them the ability to format the text a little by adding line breaks in the job description text that will be visible on the front end.

The job openings are stored in a MySQL database.

Example of what I'm talking about:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis quam sollicitudin, bibendum enim a, vulputate turpis.

Nullam urna purus, varius eget purus quis, facilisis lacinia nibh. Ut in blandit erat.
```

I've would like the breaks to happen when my client hits enter / return on the keyboard.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

### ------------UPDATE------------

okay so after much trial and error I got it somewhat working.
I added this line in my upload / action code.

```
$description = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']));
```

Full upload code is:

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/connections/dbconnect.php");



$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["date"]);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["description"]);
$description = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']));

// Insert record into database by executing the following query:
$sql="INSERT INTO hire (title, description, date) "."VALUES('$title','$description','$date')";
$retval = mysql_query($sql);


echo "The position was added to employment page.<br />
<a href='employment.php'>Post another position.</a><br />";

?>
```

Then on my form I added this to the textarea, but I get an error.
FYI that is line 80 the error is refering to.

```
Position Details:<br />
<textarea name="description" rows="8"><?php echo str_replace("<br />","",$description); ?></textarea>
</div>
```

Here is what the error looks like.

[image]

Here is my results page code:

```
<?php
$images = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hire ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10");
while ($image=mysql_fetch_array($images))
{
    
    ?>
<li data-id="id-<?=$image["id"] ?>">
<div class="box white-bg">
<h2 class="red3-tx"><?=$image["title"] ?> <span class="date-posted blue2-tx"><?=$image["date"] ?></span></h2>
<div class="dotline"></div>
<article class="blue3-tx"><?=$image["description"] ?><br />
<br />

For more information please call ###-###-####.</article>
</div>
</li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

If I delete all that error copy and write out a real position with line breaks it works.
I have no idea how to fix the error though.
Again any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: When storing the information in to the database, look in to running the `nl2br()` function.

Comment: @Karl this is WRONG approach. Use info `nl2br()` while **displaying** data

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it at all, using it before or after really doesn't matter.

Comment: Why store tag into database when you can avoid it. If you wanna allow `<br>`, you might also allow `<p>`, and other things too. Goodluck in tag stripping.

Comment: maybe you want to see my edit at my answer to solve you second problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `str_replace`

```
$statement = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis quam sollicitudin, bibendum enim a, vulputate turpis.

Nullam urna purus, varius eget purus quis, facilisis lacinia nibh. Ut in blandit erat."

$statement = str_replace(chr(13),"<br/>", $statement);

query example : INSERT INTO table (statement) VALUES ('$statement');
```

hope this can help you

**EDIT :**

if you want display the result at textarea from database u can using this code

```
$des = $row['description'] //my assumption that your feild name at table inside mySQL is description

Position Details:<br />
<textarea name="description" rows="8"><?php echo str_replace("<br />",chr(13),$des); ?></textarea>
</div>
```

hope this edit can help your second problem

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm just confused on where to add
`$des = $row['description']`

and besides replacing the echo in the textarea is there anything else I need to remove. Also , Yes the field name is description.

Comment: still don't seem to get it. I added that `$des = $row['description']` to my results page, but not sure if I did it right. I posted my code at the top if you don't mind taking a look at it.

Comment: are you mean you want put description inside <article></article> ??

Comment: LOL what do you mean..? you think I should change to <p></p>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41840/discussion-between-daugaard47-and-hans)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by answering a couple of questions first

- Do I want my database to store html-formatted user input?
- Is the data going to be editable afterwards?

Since you seem to want only nl2br, a simple approach would be to save the content as is in the database, then use [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) on the output side as Marcin Orlowski suggested.

Comment: To answer you questions Q1: Not sure does it really hurt to store tags in the database? Q2: Yes.  I'm going to go try some of these solutions in the thread. See what works best for me.